# Игра "камень-ножницы-бумага". Как сделать цикл бесконечным?

Tags: python, циклы

```
import random
ver = 0
while (ver == 0):
        player = int(input("1 - камень, 2 - ножницы, 3 - бумага. "))
        if (player == 1 or player == 2 or player == 3):
            ver = 1    
if player == 1:
        print("Вы выбрали камень.")  
if player == 2:
        print("Вы выбрали ножницы.") 
if player == 3:
        print("Вы выбрали бумагу.")  
comp = random.randint(1, 3)
if comp == 1:
        print("Компьютер выбрал камень.") 
if comp == 2:
        print("Компьютер выбрал ножницы.")
if comp == 3:
        print("Компьютер выбрал бумагу.")
if player == comp:
        win = 0
if player == 1 and comp == 2:
        win = 1 
if player == 1 and comp == 3:
        win = 2 
if player == 2 and comp == 1:
        win = 2  
if player == 2 and comp == 3:
        win = 1 
if player == 3 and comp == 1:
        win = 1
if player == 3 and comp == 2:
        win = 2
if win == 0:
        print("Ничья!")
if win == 1:
        print("Победил игрок!")
if win == 2:
        print("Победил компьютер!")
```

Comment: Нет ничего проще - `while True:`

Comment: это понятно,только выдаёт ошибку

Comment: 1. Отступы имеют значение. 2. Воспользуйтесь поиском https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B+%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0+python

Comment: Дети стюардесс играют в "мясо, рыба, курица".

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ. 1е - лучше использовать while True. 2е - у вас были не правильно поставлены отступы. В питоне то, что входил в цикл должно быть на 4 пробела правее, чем начало блока.

```
import random

while True:
    player = int(input("1 - камень, 2 - ножницы, 3 - бумага. "))
    if (player == 1 or player == 2 or player == 3):
        ver = 1
    if player == 1:
        print("Вы выбрали камень.")
    if player == 2:
        print("Вы выбрали ножницы.")
    if player == 3:
        print("Вы выбрали бумагу.")
    comp = random.randint(1, 3)
    if comp == 1:
        print("Компьютер выбрал камень.")
    if comp == 2:
        print("Компьютер выбрал ножницы.")
    if comp == 3:
        print("Компьютер выбрал бумагу.")
    if player == comp:
        win = 0
    if player == 1 and comp == 2:
        win = 1
    if player == 1 and comp == 3:
        win = 2
    if player == 2 and comp == 1:
        win = 2
    if player == 2 and comp == 3:
        win = 1
    if player == 3 and comp == 1:
        win = 1
    if player == 3 and comp == 2:
        win = 2
    if win == 0:
        print("Ничья!")
    if win == 1:
        print("Победил игрок!")
    if win == 2:
        print("Победил компьютер!")
```

Comment: Написали про 3 пробела, поставили в коде 4. Переменная ver не используется. Там if логичнее переписать на что то вида `player < 1 or player > 3: print('неверное число') break` что бы заново начиналось, если число не от 1 до 3

Comment: @SwaD там стоит tab, а не 4 пробела, так как я пользуюсь pycharm и он сам рекомендует использовать tab.
Далее по поводу рекомендации по поводу условия - ваше замечание верное.  Однако я не знаю, что за переменная ver, может она использовалась где-то до этого

Comment: Pycharm не может рекомендовать использовать таб, потому что сам питон предписывает использовать 4 пробела. https://pep8.org/

Comment: @Эникейщик ошибся, спасибо за исправление